# SQL: Error when trying to filter out all dates older than the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, date

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008. 
I have a table that stores dates in datetime format (i.e.`2012-01-21 15:00:00.000`)

I'm trying to filter out all the dates older than "today".  So I was attempting to do so by using the query below.

```
SELECT Date
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE Date >= GETDATE()
```

When I run that though, I get the following error.

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks for the help and let me know if I need to provide more information!

**More Information:**

[Date] is of type DateTime in MyTable.

I also have a View that simply selects [Date] and does no manipulation

I'm accessing [Date] via the View

Comment: What is the type of the `Date` column in your table?

Comment: That sounds like the Date column is an VARCHAR/NVARCHAR rather than a DATETIME. So whilst the date/times may be formatted like a date time, they aren't being stored as one as far as the schema is concerned. Can you confirm the database schema?

Comment: I checked the DataType for my Date column and it says 'datetime' however I am querying a View that is comprised partially from that table. So does the DataType get lost when it is access via my View?

Comment: It depends how the view extracts the data. The datatype should not be lost UNLESS the view is manipulating the data.

Comment: @Chris J, for the Date part it simply Selects the date from the table.. `SELECT D.[Date] FROM dbo.MyTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what locale your in as this ***will*** matter. The most likely possibility is that your DATE column isn't a DATETIME. You don't say what locale your in, but (as an example) US and UK datetime formats are treated differently when in reverse format.

UK sees the date as `yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss.fff`
US sees the date as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff`

For example, this throws an error:

```
SET LANGUAGE british
GO
SELECT CAST ('1999-01-21 10:11:12.345' AS DATETIME)
GO
```

However if you change the locale to `us_english`, it will parse correctly.

If you want to gurantee it's always going to be parsed as `yyyy-mm-dd`, then you need to be strict and use the full ISO spec by specifying `Z` between the date and time, e.g.,: `1999-01-21Z10:11:12.345` will parse in the same way in both locales.

Ultimately, you want to change the `Date` column to a datatype of `DATETIME`, but you may need to temporarialy change your locale to be able to do this sucessfully; i.e.:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
GO
ALTER TABLE [...]
GO
SET LANGUAGE british
GO
```

Yet another fun 'gotcha' to watch out for when manipulating date/time data.

*Sidenote: no I don't know why the Microsoft think us over in Blighty see the date as yyyy-dd-mm ... I've never encountered this format. Could be inherited from European formats?*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your column is not a `DATETIME` data type after all. It is probably `VARCHAR` or similar. If you provide the DDL for the creation of the table, that would allow a more specific answer.

Comment: I used ISDATE(Date) but I guess that returns True even if it is a varchar as long as it's in a correct format?

Comment: Ideally, you would change the data type in your table to DATETIME or similar.

Comment: Correct: snipped from sql books online ... "The following example shows you how to use ISDATE to test whether a character string is a valid datetime."

Comment: @daveomcd I was just suggesting that in my answer. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx - *ISDATE is deterministic only if you use it with the CONVERT function, if the CONVERT style parameter is specified, and style is not equal to 0, 100, 9, or 109.*

Comment: @daveomcd - Yep, IsDate() is specifically for checking strings, not dates :)

Comment: I checked the DataType for my Date column and it says 'datetime' however I am querying a View that is comprised partially from that table. So does the DataType get lost when it is access via my View?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change this to:

```
SELECT [Date]
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE [Date] <= GETDATE()
```

That type of Column is [Date]????

Answer (score 0):

If your date column is `VARCHAR/NVARCHAR` you need to convert that value to `DATETIME`. From your example, the right format should be:

```
SELECT [Date]
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,[Date],121) >= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL will implicitly convert a varchar to a datatime if you are comparing it to a datetime.  The issue you're getting is that there is a record in your table that is not in a datetime format.

GOOD EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
    SELECT '2010-01-21 15:00:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2012-01-21 05:30:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-21 07:45:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2020-01-21 11:20:00.000' [Date]
) x

SELECT *
FROM #Temp
WHERE [Date] > GETDATE()

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

BROKEN EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
    SELECT '2010-01-21 15:00:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2012-01-21 05:30:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-21 07:45:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'a2020-01-21 11:20:00.000' [Date]
) x

SELECT *
FROM #Temp
WHERE [Date] > GETDATE()

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

The 'a' in the last record of the broken example will cause the error your getting.

WORK AROUND

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
    SELECT '2010-01-21 15:00:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2012-01-21 05:30:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-21 07:45:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'a2020-01-21 11:20:00.000' [Date]
) x

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE([Date]) = 1 THEN [Date] ELSE '' END [Date]
    FROM #Temp
) x
WHERE [Date] > GETDATE()

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

BETTER OPTION

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
    SELECT '2010-01-21 15:00:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2012-01-21 05:30:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-21 07:45:00.000' [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'a2020-01-21 11:20:00.000' [Date]
) x

SELECT *
FROM #Temp
WHERE CASE WHEN ISDATE([Date]) = 1 THEN [Date] ELSE '' END > GETDATE()

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: Is there something I can add to the WHERE clause to ignore those that aren't of the right type?

Comment: @daveomcd I've added a work around.  The only issue with that is if there are more records you want in you select you'll have to add them to the nested select.  The Case statement should filter out the bad records.

Comment: @daveomcd I added a better option.  This will allow you to still get all the other records in you table with a *, but be able to filter on the [Date] field.

Comment: Alright I'm about to take a look at it.  I noticed there is actually another view that it has to pass through and I guess you would call it a derived table? (i.e. ... FROM (SELECT [DATE] FROM VIEW)) So maybe that causes it to lose it's datatype.  Thanks for all the examples!